# Swift: Utilizing CLLocationManagerDelegate and CoreLocation.framework results in "Use of undeclared type" error

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I'm going off a youtube video that gives a basic example of utilizing the location services of Xcode to program a sort of maps user interface to a program. I followed the steps in the video of setting up the program and get an assumedly simple "Use of undeclared type" error when trying to compile the application.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrdIL44T6FQ - Link to the youtube video.

The problem occurs at the class creation line.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{                                                        // ^ Use of undeclared type

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreate-d.
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations.last

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordingate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))

    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    self.location.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, difFailWithError error: NSError)
{
    print("Errors: " + error.localizedDescription)
}


}
```

I'm not sure why the error is occurring. 
I added the CoreLocation.framework in the "Link Binary With Libraries" section. I made sure to add the "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" to the Info.plist.
I connected the Map View Kit to the code itself at 2:26 in the video.

Other ways to go about doing this is also of interest. I'm solely trying to get a basic location services clearance to run in a program.

Version: Xcode Version 7.3.1

Answer (score 14):

In swift

I was missing importing CoreLocation. I have added following line on top of my file and it worked.

```
import CoreLocation
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a new project and followed the steps in the video again and the project now works appropriately. The only thing that may have caused the issue was I checked off Core Data when creating the project. I do not believe this is exactly why it was throwing an error, but if you run into a similar situation make sure this box is left empty.